# how to design the page for all screen sizes?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

Previously in Windows Phone 8, the page was the same on all screen sizes, WVGA,WGXA..

But now in Windows Phone Runtime, I see I have no control over it. font size of this text below, may change after user changes his phone settings:

```
<TextBlock Text="Your Name:" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Normal"/>
```

and it won't fit in the page.

How to design the page for all screen sizes the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about user changing the text size in phone settings, you can disable that in your TextBlocks by setting the IsTextScaleFactorEnabled property to false.

Read more about [Meeting requirements for accessible text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868163.aspx).

Other than that, just keep writing your app in fluid containers, such as Grid with star sizes etc. and it should be OK.